How to Dynamically Select a ChangeNotifierProvider Based on a Condition in Flutter?
I am working on a Flutter app where I need to dynamically determine which ChangeNotifierProvider to use based on a specific condition (an enum type). Here is the code I have:
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) {
    switch (widget.type) {
      case MasterDataType.block:
        return di.locator<BlockProvider>();
      case MasterDataType.employee:
        return di.locator<EmployeeProvider>();
      default:
        return di.locator<VehicleProvider>();
    }
  },
  builder: (context, _) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("List of <SelectedProvider>")),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text("Data from ${context.watch<SelectedProvider>().data}"),
      ),
    );
  },
);

However, when I run this code, the ChangeNotifierProvider does not infer the correct generic type (ChangeNotifierProvider<BlockProvider>, ChangeNotifierProvider<EmployeeProvider>, or ChangeNotifierProvider<VehicleProvider>). Instead, it defaults to ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>.
My questions are:

How can I make the ChangeNotifierProvider dynamically select the correct provider and infer the proper type?

Is there a better approach for dynamically selecting the provider based on widget.type?


Here is some additional context about my setup:

I am using GetIt for dependency injection.

MasterDataType is an enum with the following values:
enum MasterDataType { block, employee, vehicle }

Each provider (BlockProvider, EmployeeProvider, VehicleProvider) extends ChangeNotifier.


Thank you for your guidance!
I tried dynamically selecting the ChangeNotifierProvider by using a switch statement in the create method, as shown in the code above. I expected the provider to infer the correct generic type (ChangeNotifierProvider<BlockProvider>, ChangeNotifierProvider<EmployeeProvider>, or ChangeNotifierProvider<VehicleProvider>) based on the widget.type.
However, instead of inferring the specific provider type, the ChangeNotifierProvider defaults to ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>, which causes issues when I try to use context.watch<BlockProvider>() or other specific types later in the widget tree.
